# why scala lambda with _ can't using && to combine two bool expression

Tags: scala, lambda

As far as I understand .
_ is a short lambda to omit a=>

i find this code (can find here [scala-function-true-power](http://www.scala-tour.com/#/function-true-power))

```
val file = List("warn 2013 msg", "warn 2012 msg", "error 2013 msg", "warn 2013 msg")
val size = file.filter(_.contains("warn")).filter(_.contains("2013")).size
//val size1 = file.filter(_.contains("warn") && _.contains("2013")).size
val size2 = file.filter( a=> a.contains("warn") &&  a.contains("2013")).size
println("cat file | grep 'warn' | grep '2013' | wc : "  +size )
```

the line to get size1 has syntax error,looks like it can't recognize the "_" ,it's not a element in fileList.

but i use a=>,the normal kind,it works good .

so,why the scala work by this way?

is there more difference in _ and a=> ?

Comment: my scala version is 2.11.6

Comment: `file.filter(_.contains("warn") && _.contains("2013"))` == `file.filter((a, b) => a.contains("warn") && b.containts("2013"))`

Comment: I see , just a syntactic sugar... thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of the place holder as being matched with the lambda's arguments positionnally.

The first occurrence of the `_` is matched with the first argument, the second occurence is matched with the second argument, etc.

As the other answers have shown, this means that using the placeholder twice will be desugared as trying to pass a lamba with 2 arguments to the filter which only expects one.

In your example :

```
val size = file.filter(_.contains("warn") && _.contains("2013")).size
```

would be desugared as

```
val size = file.filter((a,b)=>a.contains("warn") &&  b.contains("2013")).size
```

which will not compile since filter expects a predicate `p: A => Boolean`

Now, a reason the placeholder is matched positionnally is to avoid ambiguity in lambdas with more than one argument.

How can the compiler guess the correct implementation for the following case if the place holder can be reused multiple times for the same argument:

```
file.fold("")(_++_)
```

Should it be desugared as :

```
file.fold("")((a,b)=> a++b )
```

or as

```
file.fold("")((a,b)=> a++a )
```

or as

```
file.fold("")((a,b)=> b++b )
```

and worse, what would you expect for

```
file.fold("")(_++_++_)
```

There is no general way for the compiler to infer the correct implementation.

One might argue for relaxing the constraint when the expected lambda only accepts one argument. I suggest doing a more detailed research before taking the first steps to the [scala improvement process](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/sip-submission.html) as it seems likely that this particular design decision has been challenged and explained before.

If you are worried about the performance of iterating over the list twice (which is the case when you write)

```
file.filter(_.contains("warn")).filter(_.contains("2013")).size
```

In theory it should be possible for the compiler to detect that both filters can be applied within the same iteration. 
In scala, the collections are eager by default but you can get the *lazy* evaluation by using views. 
The current implementation has known issues which are [being worked on](https://github.com/scala/slip/blob/master/text/0027-collection-view-redesign.md). Other collection implementations in scala are actively being developed to be able to combine transformations and computations by default (see [psp-std](https://github.com/paulp/psp-std) for example)

Comment: the best answer here, kudos!

Answer (score 6):

In scala, any _ placeholder is matched against the passed arguments in the context of calling function. So for example if the signature of the function you are trying to use is `f : A ⇒ B` and you are calling something like `collectionOfFunctA.map(_.f)` - Scala compiler will infer the correct type of the function and will use the first underscore to put the actual item from a collection and call the function `f` over it. But if you will try to write it as `collectionOfFunctA.map(_.f + _.size)` - that will fail, because Scala compiler will pick up the first placeholder as of type that has function `f` defined, and the second underscore will not match any function in the context. So it will expect to have **a function that takes two parameters instead of one**.

[More on this](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/quick-explanation-of-scalas-syntax)

Answer (score 3):

As jdevelop says, but here in the words of the compiler/REPL:

```
scala> val size1 = file.filter(_.contains("warn") && _.contains("2013")).size
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) => x$1.contains("warn").$amp$amp(x$2.contains("2013")))
       val size1 = file.filter(_.contains("warn") && _.contains("2013")).size
                               ^
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1: <error>, x$2) => x$1.contains("warn").$amp$amp(x$2.contains("2013")))
       val size1 = file.filter(_.contains("warn") && _.contains("2013")).size
                                                     ^
```

You see that hint:  for expanded function ((x$1, x$2) => x$1.contains("warn").$amp$amp(x$2.contains("2013")))

It is expecting 2 parameters while there is just one.